# Traefik CLI override file frontend / backend

Tags: traefik

I'd like to set up or override the frontend/backend settings in traefik via the CLI.

In TOML I can define

```
[file]
[frontends]
  [frontends.traefik-in]
  entryPoints = ["http"]
  backend = "traefik-out"

[backends]
  [backends.traefik-out]
    [backends.traefik-out.servers]
      [backends.traefik-out.servers.default]
        url = "http://someserver:someport"
```

I believe I should be able to override this on the CLI. But it does not appear to recognise these options.

`traefik --file.frontends=""`
"Error parsing command: unknown flag: --file.frontends"

What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Backends and forntends are a part of the [dynamic configuration](https://docs.traefik.io/v1.7/basics/#dynamic-traefik-configuration).

The CLI allows to manage the [static configuration](https://docs.traefik.io/basics/#configuration).

So you cannot override dynamic configuration by using the CLI.

Comment: Thanks! As traefik does not allow environment overrides, I've created a custom docker container for this.